# razzle SSR rendering react, doesn't run from initial installation instructions

Tags: reactjs, server-side-rendering, razzle

running the basic install for razzle, I get the error "Cannot GET /", this is what I did:

https://github.com/jaredpalmer/razzle

npx create-razzle-app my-app
cd my-app
npm start

Answer (score 1):

For people stumbling on this:

in template need change in client.js

```
 import BrowserRouter from 'react-router-dom/BrowserRouter';
```

to

```
 import {BrowserRouter}  from 'react-router-dom';
```

and in App.js

```
import Route from 'react-router-dom/Route';
import Switch from 'react-router-dom/Switch';
```

to

```
import {Route,Switch} from 'react-router-dom';
```

Source : 
https://github.com/jaredpalmer/razzle/issues/1022